# Will charge accelerate if we apply voltage accross superconductor?

Tags: electric-current

Will charge accelerate if we apply voltage accross superconductor

Comment: Ofcourse. Charges accelerate in the presence of electric fields. The only exception is that in the steady state, if your PD is not across a e.g, closed loop  the Arrangement of charges cancel out the external field  causing there to be a equipotential and thus no acceleration. But transiently  there I'd always acceleration